# How to declare an array without specifying its size, but with an initializer inside a class in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, c++17

It is allowed to declare an array without explicitly stating its size, if it has an initializer:

```
// very fine: decltype(nums) is deduced to be int[3]
int nums[] = { 5, 4, 3 };
```

However the same doesn't work when the array is declared in a class:

```
class dummy_class
{
    // incomplete type is not allowed (VS 2019 c++17)
    int nums[] = { 5, 4, 3 }; 
};
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because it's simply not allowed by the C++ language specification? Perhaps use a `std::vector<int>` instead?

Comment: Because ISO said so.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried, but my type is non-copyable, (I used `int` as an example), so I can't use initializer-list-construction at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not allowed because non-static data members might be initialized in different ways (with different sizes), including [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), ... But the size of array must be fixed and known at compile-time, which can't be postponed until the initialization. e.g.

```
class dummy_class
{
    int nums[] = { 5, 4, 3 }; 
    dummy_class(...some_parameters) : nums { 5, 4, 3, 2 } ()
    dummy_class(...some_other_parameters) : nums { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } ()
};
```

Comment: Also aggregate initialization of the class itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not allowed, you can do one of these two things:

- Either use the constructors/methods for initialization along with vector type declaration.
- Or try making the variable static, but I am afraid that may not be helpful in your case.